# Вызов функции с непределенными заранее параметрами

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как вызвыть функцию с параметрами не определенными заранее. То есть у меня есть массив например int arr[15], и я хочу передать все элементы массива как параметры. Но проблема в том, что массив может быть любого размера. Функции имеют вид int a(int a, int b, int c...), требуется вызвать их имея этот массив. Конечно можно передать массив в функцию и не заниматься лишней работой, однако хочется упростить написание функций и сделать нормальные параметры, а не вытаскивание значений из массива. 
Последний раз я решал такую порблему через ассемблерные вставки параметров функции и ее вызов. Возможно есть более простой метод?

UPD. Все же мне интересно, почему нельзя сказать компилятору, что хочу вызвать функцию void* test, с плавающим числом параметров, вот их количество и вот указатели на переменные. Через ассемблер это делается легко. Не сильно опаснее va_list.

Comment: >Конечно можно передать массив в функцию и не заниматься лишней работой, однако хочется упростить написание функций

эммм...вы считаете, что вот это 

    void foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
    {
 cout << a << " ";
 cout << b << " ";
 cout << c << " ";
 cout << d << " ";
 cout << e << " ";
    }

    
  проще чем это? 

    void anotherFoo(int* a, int sz)
    {
 for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
     cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  };
    foo(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);

Весьма оригинальное представление о простоте

Comment: Пишете на C++? Используйте `std::vector` и не морочьте голову. Ассемблерные вставки — вы не ошиблись тысячелетием?

Comment: В случае printf() конечно да, проще, но, у меня случай func(int z, int d, int f, int ...); и для вменяемой работы придется добавлять int &z=a[0]... и именно от этого я хочу избавиться.


VladD, если говорить о таком способе, то у меня есть более лучшие варианты, чем использовать вектор.

Comment: @mikelsv, `va_list` просто прячет все ассемблерные вставки, которые Вы бы написали, внутри себя. Это, вероятно, достаточно удобно, иначе придется писать код, рассчитанный под конкретный компилятор (порядок аргументов там учитывать, способ их передачи и прочую низкоуровневую магию). Оно надо?

Comment: Ага, а ... оказывается просто кладет параметры в стек как для обычной функции. Значит можно не страдать ерундой, а написать прототип и вызывать функцию через него. Вот пример такого безобразия: http://pastebin.com/kg0LarqG . Но опять же придется писать свой вызов для каждого количества переменных. Хотя, наверно можно попробовать передать массив int[200], а функция пусть возьмет только нужное количество параметров. Полагаю нужно указать, что функции обязаны вызываться как cdecl.

Comment: Короче, у меня предложение - давайте заведем вопрос "создания реализации вызова функций интерпретируемого языка" отдельно в разделе исследования. Вопрос действительно интересный и многогранный.

Comment: @gecube, я там добавил ответы в ответ. Это не вопрос. Пишем прототип функции, определяем формат параметров, массив это будет или динамический список. Пишем функции под прототип и вызываем. Вопрос лишь в выборе.

Comment: @gecube, интересное предложение. Особенно если кто-то предложит варианты и для 32 и для 64-бит (в X-64 первые параметры в регистрах передаются).

Answer (score 7):

Пример с variadric templates в дополнение к ответу [@gecube](/users/907/gecube):

Скажу сразу, их так лучше не использовать =) векторы и массивы лучше обходятся постаринке. В целом очень похоже на va_list, поэтому это не совсем то, что хотел ТС.

```
int sum() { // конец рекурсивно-шаблонной вакханалии
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int sum(T value, Args... args) { // функция вида "один элемент и все оставшиеся"
    // складываем тот элемент, что знаем, и вызываем себя для всех остальных элементов
    return value + sum(args...); 
}

// вызов функции 
std::cout << sum(5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5);
```

[Попробовать на Ideone](http://ideone.com/AjAhAD)

Еще один вариант, но с std::initializer_list<>. Запустить на [Ideone](http://ideone.com/OqH9cH). Выглядит так:

```
int sum(std::initializer_list<int > intarray) {
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(intarray), std::end(intarray), 0);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << sum({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 за высокотехнологичный пример!

Хотя я бы сделал хвостовую рекурсию (правда, не уверен, воспользуется ли этим компилятор).

Comment: Код: http://ideone.com/GiLRay

Comment: Все-таки шаблоны гораздо надежнее, чем макросы и va_list'ы. Шансы написать бяку, которая заваливается при каких-то определенных условиях с ними, гораздо меньше. Даешь шаблоны в массы!

Comment: @VladD вы про первый пример? Синтаксически это и есть хвостовая рекурсия. По факту (если я правильно понимаю) будет просто много инстанциированных шаблонов (по 1 на каждое кол-во аргументов), которые будут вызывать друг друга. В релизе они, конечно же, заинлайнятся друг в друга.

Answer (score 3):

В любом случае, без указателей не обойтись. Принципиальных способов решения проблемы два:

1. Передача в ф-цию указателя и размера массива: `int func (int *arr, int size);` Концепция такая же как у стандартных ф-ций работы с памятью и строками (`memset`, `memcpy` и пр.)
2. Использование специальной возможности создания ф-ций с переменным числом аргументов. Для этого нужно применить механизм va_list. Дрянь редкостная, но работает. Следует обратить внимание (особое!) на проверку того, что получено столько аргументов, сколько нужно, иначе привет разрушения стека.
3. Если размер массива фиксирован сверху, то можно сделать серию ф-ций с разным числом аргументов.

вот так:

```
int func(int a);
int func(int a, int b);
int func(int a, int b, int c);
....
```

Компилятор сам выберет нужную. Или можно задействовать механизм параметров по умолчанию:

```
int func(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0) // и т.д.
```

В этом случае все неиспользованные параметры ф-ции будут инициализированы теми значения, которые укажет программист.

Также отмечу, что для генерации однотипных ф-ций можно использовать макросы или шаблоны.

Comment: Можно еще использовать variadric templates

Comment: @IronVbif, пример в студию!

Comment: Первый вариант самый лучший, однако у каждого элемента массива может быть свое имя и было бы намного проще работать с ними как с переменными.

Да, va_list это ад. Как-то общался, потом плюнул и воспользовался третьим вариантом, кстати получился нормальный printf.

В принципе я хожу вокруг третьего варианта. Думаю написать 50 прототипов, их точно должно хватить.

Answer (score 2):

На твоём месте я бы засунул всё в вектор и не парился бы.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)   ( sizeof(arr) / sizeof arr[0] )

void CallMethodWithVector(const std::vector<int> &refParams)
{
    //do what you want here with your params
}

void CallerFunction(void)
{
    int arr[15];
    // set param values here
    // ......
    std::vector<int> aParams(arr, arr + ARRAY_SIZE(arr) )
    CallMethodWithVector(aParams)
}
```

Если тип параметров заранее не известен, то просто сделаешь CallMethodWithVector шаблоном.

Comment: макрос ARRAY_SIZE уже существует и называется [`_countof()`][1]

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms175773(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Гм, мне кажется вы не поняли суть задачи. Заворачивание готового решения в вектор только усложняет работу.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было сделать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Берем функцию:
int test(int a, char *b, double c){
    printf("%d %s %f", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

// Делаем прототип:
typedef int (*callfunc)(...);

// И пишем код:
int main(int args, char* arg[]){
    // параметры функции, которые хотим передать.
    double d=11; int str[4]={15, (unsigned int)"text"}; memcpy(str+2, &d, 8);

    // структура, которая будет полностью скопирована в стек. Если передавать str, то будет передан указатель, а нам нужно передать именно данные.
    struct efunc_s{ unsigned int a[4]; };

    // получаем адрес функции.
    callfunc cf=(callfunc)test;

    // Приводим в вид, который будет скопирован в стек.
    efunc_s &s=*(efunc_s*)&str;

   // вызываем функцию
    (*cf)(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Под g++ собирать с -m32.

UPD. Комментарии больше не добавляются.

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), я пишу под MSVC, тут все работает. Под 64 бита оно падает. Чуть поправил, но параметры передаются не так. Clang обойдется. -O3 работает, в студии тоже. Остальную оптимизацию можно убрать ради работоспособности. В принципе, если тип данных будет один, то можно и написать эти 50 функций, но покане хочется отказываться от возможности вызывать функцию с разными типами данных.

[[[[@gecube](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube), нет, не этих внешних функций. Есть интерпретируемый язык программирования, в него можно подключить функции, скажем print(string str), задача вызвать ее. Учитывая, что таких функций может быть много с их вызовом начинаются сложности.

[[[[@gecube](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube) именно, язык Шредингера. Именно поэтому я не воспользовался передачей параметров в виде массива, но мне все равно нужен способ вызывать их. Интерпретация или компиляция, на выбор.

Comment: Ого, `memcpy`, cast указателя в `unsigned int`. Вы хотите поставить рекорд по количеству UB на строку кода? Интересно, падает ли это с `-O3`?

Comment: Нет, работает. Тут вроде и падать негде. Я показываю, как оно может работать, совать ли туда пальцы решать вам. )

Comment: @mikelsv: у вас тут в каждой строке pointer aliasing между несвязанными типами, это чистое UB.

Comment: Это работает на двух компиляторах и не падает при оптимизации. Важно, что это работает и работает так как и предполагается. Других вариантов решения нет и я предпочту пользоваться этим.

Comment: Код плохой. Уверен, что какая-либо мелочь (типа настроек aligment) и он упадет.

Comment: Хм. Это как бы да. При использовании постараюсь учесть все вероятные проблемы. А здесь хотелось получить рабочий вариант.

Comment: @mikelsv, объясните все-таки, что Вы хотите получить в конечном счете? Какую конкретно задачу решаем? Все-таки те же variadic templates выглядят поизящнее.

Comment: А зачем вам такой механизм?. Вы пишите свой RPC?

Comment: Я пишу свой язык программирования. Механизм нужен для подключения внешних функций.

Comment: @mikelsv: работает? На MSVC тоже? На Clang пробовали? На 64-битной архитектуре пробовали? Со включенным whole program optimization, поместив все функции в один файл, пробовали?

Comment: @mikelsv 

> Механизм нужен для подключения внешних функций.

каких именно? Механизмы для подключения внешних ф-ций существуют. Народ ведь как-то использует `LoadLibrary` на пару с `GetProcAddress`. Другой вопрос, что таким макаром можно сделать не все и не с любыми модулями, где лежат внешние ф-ции.

> задача вызвать функцию знаяя ее параметры.

Скажем так - вызвать ф-цию БЕЗ знания параметров и ее адреса и/или имени, ну, и соглашения касательно вызова (cdecl, stdcall - я про это) не получится.

Comment: > Я пишу свой язык программирования. Механизм нужен для подключения внешних функций.

Ну, пока неконкретно. Вариантов механизма масса. Тем более, что ЯП может быть интерпретируемый, а может быть нет...

Comment: Да, для вызова функций из .so это м.б. интересно.

Только муторный какой-то способ, но может \#define-ы его как-то скрасят...